# $ T = V|T| $ in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ T \in B(H) $, where $ H $ is a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. Is it true that $ T = V|T| $ for some unitary operator $ V $?

Comment: What is $|T|$? ${}{}$

Comment: True. Polar decomposition, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition Note the decomposition is unique when $T$ is invertible. Are you looking for a proof?

Comment: @julien: Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T = U \Sigma V^*$ be the SVD of $T$. Then $T = (U V^*) (V \Sigma V^*)$ will suffice.

Comment: why SVD for an operator?

Comment: Interesting, +1. The SVD was not very popular where and when I studied. I never realized that it yields a polar decomposition so easily.

Comment: I think the SVD & Shur decomposition are two (mostly numerical) tools that are well worth inserting into linear algebra courses...